# What does "OCBC Skyway" stand for?

Tags: singapore, parks-and-gardens

I've read all about the [OCBC Skyway](http://www.gardensbythebay.com.sg/en/attractions/ocbc-skyway.html) in Singapore's Gardens by the Bay, but I can't find out what "OCBC" stands for, if anything.

[image]

Comment: LMGTFY: is it not Oversea-Chinese Banking Corporation, AKA OCBC Bank, headquartered in Singapore?

Comment: @pnuts: Do you have any complaints against the OP's actions? The question seems to me to be perfectly valid. And if the OP is, as you seem to claim, not concerned about the meaning of "OCBC", then why would they even ask?

Comment: Not everybody comes back here every hour - some people actually _work_, I heard, up to 8 hours a day, or even more. Give him a day.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCBC_Bank

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel

Comment: @JonathanReez: yes it is. Just as [this one](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77045/what-does-shin-in-a-japanese-train-station-name-mean) or [this one](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77587/what-does-kmb-2016-mean-in-when-written-on-a-church-wall) are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OCBC Bank sponsors the "OCBC Skyway" and "OCBC Sound and Light Show" at Gardens by the Bay, as evidenced by [this press release](https://www.ocbc.com/assets/pdf/media/2012/april/120430_(websitel)media%20release%20-%20ocbc%20gb%20%20announcement%20(final).pdf).

The reason they don't specify this directly on the official page you link is presumably that OCBC is one of the largest banks in the region, and most locals would see it like having to explain that the "HSBC World Rugby Sevens Series" is named that because it's sponsored by HSBC.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSBC